# available data (DSM FIRST, DSM LAST, DTM, BUILDING FOOTPRINT) how to obtain buildings heights?

Tags: qgis, lidar, footprint, building-heights

Lidar data: DSM (First/last) AND DTM are in.ASCII format

Footprint available extracted from OpenStreetMap.